# Python: how to embed all docstring help at package level help menu?

Tags: python, numpy, package, docstring, code-documentation

What I mean to ask is:

- TLDR:  **how do I have my package's help include all underlying docstrings?**
- I have created a package. That package has all the proper `__init__.py` files and all the proper docstrings (module, function, class, and method level docstrings). However, when I perform `help(mypackage)`, the only help provided is the help provided at that top level `__init__.py` module.

Often *package-level* help does not include all of the underlying docstrings, but *sometimes it does*.

I want to make sure that I am embedding all of the underlying docstrings.

---

For instance, within the [`numpy` package](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py) all underlying docstrings are available in the help at the command prompt, even though they are not provided at the top-level `__init__.py`.

I.e., I can type

```
>>> help(numpy)
```

and see all of the documentation, including documentation defined outside of the dunder init module.

However, many other packages, including popular ones like the [`pandas` package](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/__init__.py) do not capture all of the underlying documentation.

I.e., typing

```
>>> help(pandas)
```

only provides me the documentation defined in `__init__.py`.

**I want to create package-level documentation mirroring how `numpy` does it.**

---

I have tried to look through `numpy` to see how it is performing this magic, with no luck. I have performed Google searches, but it seems there is no way to phrase this question and get any decent links back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`numpy` shows you documentation on classes and functions defined outside `__init__.py` module because of adding their names to `__all__` variable in `__init__.py`. Try to comment lines 169-173 (don't forget to uncomment!):

```
#__all__.extend(['__version__', 'show_config'])
#__all__.extend(core.__all__)
#__all__.extend(_mat.__all__)
#__all__.extend(lib.__all__)
#__all__.extend(['linalg', 'fft', 'random', 'ctypeslib', 'ma'])
```

After doing this output of `help(numpy)` will be very limited.

Also let's reproduce this behaviour. Starting from `'/some/path'`, create folder `folder`, file named `file.py` inside it with the following content:

```
class Class:
    """Class docstring"""
```

And `__init__.py`:

```
from .file import *
```

Now let's see the help:

```
/some/path$ python3.5
>>> import folder
>>> help(folder)

Help on package folder:

NAME
    folder

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    file

FILE
    /some/path/folder/__init__.py
```

And now add this line to `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ['Class']
```

After reimporting `folder` the command `help(folder)` will contain information about `class Class` which includes your docstring:

```
Help on package folder:

NAME
    folder

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    file

CLASSES
    builtins.object
        folder.file.Class

    class Class(builtins.object)
     |  Class docstring
     |  
     |  Data descriptors defined here:
     |  
     |  __dict__
     |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
     |  
     |  __weakref__
     |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)

DATA
    __all__ = ['Class']

FILE
    /some/path/folder/__init__.py
```